# Entity Framework Encrypt Data and Descrypt in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, .net-core

I'm now try to implement Encrypt for one column inside database. but our system have two part - one part is use entity framework Core and another one use ado.NET

now the problem is our SQL is standard edition, don't have Always Encrypt module, so if we build Encrypt logic into .NET then SQL procedure part have to call CLR code, Microsoft already say not suggest of this, because it will cause MayLeakOnAbort issue, and also need to make database TRUSTWORTH and Mode to Unsafe.

if create Key in database and move logic into database, then how to retrieve Entityframework data? because data is been encrypted, then we need to call dbo.Decrypt for each record, this will cause huge performance issue.

So Is there any algorithm or solution that can encrypt and decrypt at both .NET and SQL side and result is same?

Environment: .NET Entity Framework Core 2.0, MSSQL Standard Edition 2017
Thanks.

Comment: From SQL Server 2016 SP1 onwards, Always Encrypted is available in all editions, so your original problem may not be a problem at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert really? I see MS documents still say only support enterprise edition, thank later I will try in standard edition for this.

Comment: ["(Prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP1, Always Encrypted was limited to the Enterprise Edition.)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine)